# How do You concatenate a value to an array that was retrieved through a query in sql?

Tags: postgresql, array, string-manipulation

I have a table named "mkvtable" that establishes a correspondence between individual strings and arrays of strings:

```
  word   |     mkvword
---------+-----------------
 hello   | {world,friend}
 goodbye | {home,forever}
 hi      | {fellas,ladies}
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) provided for PostgreSQL, appending a value to an array of values should be a simple matter of using the concatenation operator: "||".

However, if, I attempt to add the string `there`, to the array of strings `{fellas,ladies}` which correspond to the word `hi`, nothing appears to happen:

```
SELECT mkvword FROM mkvtable WHERE word = 'hi' || 'there';
```

PostgresSQL appears to be saying as much:

```
 mkvword
---------
(0 rows)
```

Since there are no errors thrown, I assume things are syntactically okay.

What am I doing wrong? My best guess is that psql is getting upset that I'm trying to access the array by using it's relationship to a value from the adjacent column, but that's just an uneducated guess. Perhaps this sort of query doesn't jell well with the concatenation operator?

TL;DR: How do you properly concatenate values to arrays stored in table rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, if, for example, I attempt to add the string 'there', to the array of strings '{fellas,ladies}' which correspond to the word 'hi', nothing appears to happen:

You are comparing the value of the column `word` with the string constant `'hithere'` - you are concatenating two string constants, not a string to an array column.

```
 where word = 'hi' || 'there';
```

is the same as

```
 where word = 'hithere';
```

---

It sounds as if you really want:

```
SELECT mkvword || 'there' 
FROM mkvtable 
WHERE word = 'hi';
```

If you want to change the value that is stored in the table rather than just displaying it, you need an update:

```
update mkvtable
  set mkvword = mkvword || 'there' 
where word = 'hi';
```

Comment: Perfect answer and then some. As Colin pointed out, I was just concatenating two strings and passing that as a query.

Comment: Proper solution, its working properly , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building on the fantastic answer from **a_horse_with_no_name**:

Given that I am updating an array of strings, the proper format would be as follows:

`set mkvword = mkvword || '{"there"}'`

Otherwise, psql gets mad and admonishes you as follows:

```
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_append()`:

```
update mkvtable
  set mkvword = array_append(mkvword, 'there')
where word = 'hi';
```

It is cleaner than `|| '{"there"}'` and it can handle `NULL`s in the field well:

```
SELECT array_append(NULL::character varying[], 'test');
```

```
array_append
------------
{test}
```